# Scroll panel by panel – fixed then scroll

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I'm trying to have different sections who overlap. When I scroll section 1 moves, when it's outside the window section 2 starts to move and so on.

Similar to this example:
https://wissenderkuenste.de/

Code so far:

**HTML**:

```html
<div id="section1" >
  // content    
</div>

<div id="section2" >
  // content    
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```css
#section1 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: darkgray;
  height: 500px;
}

#section2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -200px;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 500px;
}
```

**Javascript**:

```js
let sec1 = document.getElementById("section1");
let sec2 = document.getElementById("section2");

let sec1H = sec1.clientHeight;
let sec2H = sec2.clientHeight;

window.onscroll = function() {scroller()};

function scroller() {
  var winScrollDist = document.body.scrollTop ||  document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var winHeight = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;

  if (winScrollDist <= sec1H) {
    // sec1 inside view
    sec2.style.top = -200 + winScrollDist + "px";
  } else {
    // sec1 outside view
  }
}
```

This basically works, but section 2 is flickering (especially in Safari), I guess because it's moving down pixel by pixel.

Did anyone achive something similar?

Thank you!

Comment: Show us your HTML/CSS code. What have you tried so far? You need to provide us with more information and with what you have tried so far. Stackoverflow is for helping you with issues and not for doing the work for you.

Comment: Add your trial, SO is not your private coding service.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed edit! I added my code.

Comment: Can you please explain your desired functionality a little more? From running your code it doesn't at all seem to have a similar effect of your source site. the biggest thing here is that using `position:relative;` while possible is going to be a pain. It would be best to do this with `absolute` or `fixed`.

Comment: thank you `absolute` and `fixed` makes way more sense and solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is more smooth code with CSS.(JS changes classes of DOM only)

But this code requires generalizing for ease to use.

```js
window.onscroll = function( event ) {
  let sec2 = document.getElementById("section2");
  let sec3 = document.getElementById("section3");
  if ( document.documentElement.scrollTop >= 850 - 75 ) {
   if ( sec2.classList.contains( "pinned" ) ) {
      sec2.classList.add( "unpinned" );
      sec2.classList.remove( "pinned" );
    }
  }
  else {
   if ( sec2.classList.contains( "unpinned" ) ) {
   sec2.classList.add( "pinned" );
    sec2.classList.remove( "unpinned" );
    }
  }
  
  if ( document.documentElement.scrollTop >= 1700 - 150 ) {
   if ( sec3.classList.contains( "pinned" ) ) {
      sec3.classList.add( "unpinned" );
      sec3.classList.remove( "pinned" );
    }
  }
  else {
   if ( sec3.classList.contains( "unpinned" ) ) {
   sec3.classList.add( "pinned" );
    sec3.classList.remove( "unpinned" );
    }
  }

};
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 2500px;
}

#section1 {
  background-color: darkgray;
  height: 800px;
}

#section2 {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 800px;
}

#section3 {
  background-color: limegreen;
  height: 800px;
}

#section2.pinned {
  position: fixed;
  top: 75px;
}

#section2.unpinned {
  position: absolute;
  top: 850px;
}

#section3.pinned {
  position: fixed;
  top: 150px;
}

#section3.unpinned {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1700px;
}
```

```html
<div id="section1" >
  // content 1
</div>

<div id="section2" class="pinned" >
  // content 2
</div>

<div id="section3" class="pinned">
  // content 3
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Changing between `position: fixed` and `position: absolute` with the calculated `top` distance solved my problem and was what I was looking for.